# Known Issues (Audio Kit Frame work with Xcode 11 on Mojave)

Tags: xcode, audiokit

Beginner question here so apologies in advance.
I am trying to use Audiokit framework and the UI framework, however Xcode 11.3 is generating (Framework not found AudiokitUI.

I am running Mojave and using Audiokit 4.9.5,followed the instruction on audiokit.io website (https://vimeo.com/162156851)

[screenshot from my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyNPX.jpg)

Thanks in advance